# What is the easiest way for me to access my IPv6 server from IPV4?

Tags: ipv6, ssh-tunnel, ipv4

I have a Nextcloud server that works fine, but I noticed that I cannot access it from certain places. What all of these have in common is that they seem to use IPv4.

This would make sense, as IPv4 is not compatible with IPv6, and in DuckDNS, I used IPv6. I tried to set up IPv4 with port forwarding, but it didn't work, so my guess is that my ISP has IPv4 behind a NAT...

This is such a pain, because I cannot access the server from any IPv4 WiFi connection or even my own mobile data because they don't support IPv6.

I heard that SSH Tunneling and Wireguard could help to make this work, but I don't find a ton of resources on how to do that, and I tried setting up Wireguard with PiVPN, but it just doesn't seem to work because it's trying to use IPv4, that, as I've mentioned, seems to be behind NAT, making it not accessible remotely.

Could you share some resources to me to make this work?

Comment: to clarify, you're using nextcloud in your home network?

Comment: [ssh tunnelling example](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/ssh-and-http-raspberry-pi-behind-cg-nat) - you will need a VPS of course

Comment: Yes, I'm using nextcloud on a small server I have connected to my home network

Comment: well, any solution will require an external (i.e. on the internet) server, be it VPN or a VPS - or maybe "cloudflare tunnel" will be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy a domain name or get a free domain online.
2. Sign up with a free CloudFlare plan and add your domain.
3. Set up a AAAA DNS record pointing to your IPv6 server.(Make sure your IPv6 service is accessible via internet)
4. Make sure to proxy turn on proxy switch.
5. Now you can access your IPv6 service from both ipv4 and V6 via the domain name.

It is pretty straightforward and plenty of resources available online and should not take more than few minutes set it up. As an added bonus you get enterprise grade security with CloudFlare for free.